# tkinter lift() not executing in while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a python beginner. I want to bring a tkinter window to focus in while loop. What I want to do is destroy tkinter window once I click a button and recreate it again.

```
import tkinter

def get_number_from_entry(event):
    number_to_machine = NumberEntry.get()
    print("Number is {} ". format(number_to_machine))
    top.destroy()


while(True):
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.lift()
    top.bind('<Return>', get_number_from_entry)

    B = tkinter.Label(top, text="1234")
    B.pack()
    NumberEntry = tkinter.Entry(top)
    NumberEntry.insert(0, "1234")
    NumberEntry.pack()
    B = tkinter.Button(top, text='Number')
    B.bind('<Button-1>', get_number_from_entry)
    B.pack()

    top.mainloop()
    # Do some work here
```

I want to bring the tkinter to focus every time while loop re-runs. 

But it gets focus only first time. Later it doesn't get focus

Comment: What is the point in calling `mainloop()` (an infinite loop) inside an infinite loop?

Comment: When I run with 3.7.0a2 on Win 10 from IDLE, pressing the Number button kills the tk window and a new one is created on top of all the other windows.  So your title is wrong.  For finer control of focus, see doc for focus and grab methods at, for instance, http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html.  Detailed behavior may depend on OS.

Comment: BTW: tkinter has [standard dialog to ask for numer](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm)

Comment: BTW: `Button(..., command=get_number_from_entry)`